# Selected item ComboBox is not showing correct ID WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro

I have a problem that I cannot resolve.

**ShellViewModel**

```
    private IEventAggregator _events;
    private SimpleContainer _container;

    public ShellViewModel(IEventAggregator events, SimpleContainer container)
    {
       
        _events = events;
        _events.Subscribe(this);
        _container = container;

    void IHandle<CorrectionEvent>.Handle(CorrectionEvent message)
    {
         ActivateItem(_container.GetInstance<CorrectionViewModel>());
    }
```

**MenuViewModel**

```
    private IEventAggregator _events;
    private IUserModel _userModel;
    private IDModel _selectOdprto;

    public BindableCollection<IDModel> Odprto { get; set; }

    public MenuViewModel(IEventAggregator events , IUserModel userModel)
    {
        _events = events;
        _userModel = userModel;

        Task.Run(() => Data());        
    }

    public async Task Data()
    {
        DataAccessLibrary da = new DataAccessLibrary();
        Odprto = new BindableCollection<IDModel>(await da.GetData(_userModel.UserName, "Odprto"));
    }

    public IDModel SelectOdprto
    {
        get { return _selectOdprto; }
        set
        {
            _selectOdprto = value;

            _events.PublishOnUIThread(new CorrectionEvent());
            _events.PublishOnUIThread(new IDEvent(_selectOdprto.ID , _selectOdprto));
        }
    }
```

**CorrectionViewModel**

```
    private IDModel _selectedID;
    private IDataAccess _dataAccess;
    private IEventAggregator _events;
    private IUserModel _userModel;

    public int IDOdprto { get; set; }
    public BindableCollection<IDModel> IDs { get; set; }

    public  CorrectionViewModel(IDataAccess dataAccess, IEventAggregator events, IUserModel userModel)
    {
        _dataAccess = dataAccess;
        _userModel = userModel;

        Task.Run(() => Data());

        _events = events;
        _events.Subscribe(this);
    }

    public async Task Data()
    {
        DataAccessLibrary da = new DataAccessLibrary();
        IDs = new BindableCollection<IDModel>(await da.GetData(_userModel.UserName, "Odprto")); 
        NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => IDs);          
    }

    public IDModel SelectedID
    {
        get { return _selectedID; }
        set
        {
        SelectedID = message.IDModel;
        SelectedID.ID = message.IDMenu;
        NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => SelectedID);   
        }
     }



    public void Handle(IDEvent message)
    {
        _selectedID= message.IDModel;
        NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => SelectedID);
    }
```

**IDModel library**

```
public class IDModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string IZVOR { get; set; }
}
```

**IDEvent**

```
public class IDEvent
{
    public IDEvent(int _IDMenu ,  IDModel T)
    {
        IDMenu = _IDMenu;
        IDModel = T;
    }

    public int IDMenu { get; private set; }
    public IDModel IDModel { get; private set; }
}
```

**Correction XAML**

```
    <ComboBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
              ItemsSource="{Binding IDs}"  MinWidth="200"
              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedID, Mode=TwoWay}" Margin="5"
              HorizontalAlignment="Left" materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="Izberite ID"
              Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFloatingHintComboBox}" >

        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ComboBoxItem Content="{Binding ID}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ComboBox>
```

**Menu XAML**

```
    <ListBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.RowSpan="2" MinHeight="200" 
              MinWidth="200" MaxHeight="300" ItemsSource="{Binding Odprto}" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
              BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Margin="10" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectOdprto}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ID}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

So the code works but the problem is that the ComboBox is showing first item not the one that is passed with the event. Other TextBlocks are showing correct values and if I do MessageBox.Show(SelectedID.ID.ToString()); the value is correct, just the ComboBox is showing wrong items.

Comment: Just a typo: `SelectedID = message.IDModel;` => `_selectedID = message.IDModel;`

Comment: This doesn't work. :/ I allready tried. It still selects the first item.

Comment: That line can cause `StackOverflowException` because the setter calls itself. It must be fixed. Please update the code with this fix then.

Comment: Changed. Do you have any more idea how can it be fixed?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These methods looks broken, let's fix

```csharp
public IDModel SelectedID
{
    get => _selectedID;
    set
    {
        _selectedID = value;
        NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => SelectedID);   
    }
}

public void Handle(IDEvent message)
{
    SelectedID = IDs?.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == message.IDModel.ID);
}
```

Comment: What should x be?

Comment: x is element of `IDs` collection. There was a typo in the answer, fixed. So, this expression just picks an element from collection with the same `IDModel.ID` or returns `null` if not found.

Comment: `SelectedID = IDs.FirstOrDefault(_selectedID => _selectedID.ID == message.IDModel.ID); `  So this works. thank you. I hope this is correct

Comment: @Zigimun `x` was ok here,  change back. It's local variable. `FirstOrDefault(blabla => blabla.ID == message.IDModel.ID);` will work too.

Comment: I changed it back. I understand now. Marked answer as accepted. Thank you very much

Comment: @Zigimun to fugure out why it didn't work: you tried to set the selected item with value not present in the collection. Regardless of the same data inside there were different objects.

Comment: Yes. So now it accualy selects the object from the IDs and not from the IDEvent. I am preety new to C# and MVVM. So it's preety hard for me. I used mostly VB.Net and VBA before. So the learning curve is pretty high.

Comment: I have 1 more question should `Task.Run(() => Data())` be `Task.Run(async () => { await Data(); }).Wait();`  Because I have to call ViewModel to go fetch Data somehow but don't know if this is proper way.

Comment: @Zigimun Sure, refer to the documentation [`FirstOrDefault`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: @Zigimun No, leave it as it is. Not perfect but better than `.Wait()`

Comment: @Zigimun to make it perfect you may search something about "safe fire and forget asynchronous".

Comment: @Zigimun or try this, may be a bit better `_ = Data();` but not safe too in case of unhandled exception inside. In short, to be safe you may wrap `Data()`'s body in `try-catch`.

Comment: Accualy I have to Wait for data to be loaded, otherwise this answer throws an exception.

Comment: @Zigimun `NullReferenceException`? What exactly is `null`?

Comment: can't pick up ID from IDs if its loading since at the time it's null. So I have to wait till data loads

Comment: @Zigimun `SelectedID = IDs?.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == message.IDModel.ID);` updated the answer.

Comment: I know that I can put ? but than it just doesn't trigger.

Comment: @Zigimun i have no idea what _doesn't trigger_ means. `?` prevents `.FirstOrDefault` execution only if `IDs` is `null`.